# Angular scrollToAnchor not working properly in a list of elements /common.js scrollToElement is using the same scroll position for each element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a bug with anchor link angular.
I have three buttons, on click on each I should redirect to a specific part of the page.
On clicking on the first button it scrolls to the right div.
However, when I click the second or the the third ones, I have the right anchor link but it scrolls to the div of the first button.

I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftzszq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Finformations%2Finformations.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Finformations%2Finformations.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.css) with the same code of the application I am working on. It's working perfectly on stackblitz but not in my app.

While debugging I figured out that in **common.js** function **scrollToElement**, the left and top positions are the same for the 3 elements, the first div position. So the calculation is wrong for the second and the third elements and I didn't found the reason.

Here is a screenshot of the debug screen:
[image]

Do you have an idea please?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **@ViewChild** and *nativeElement* **scrollIntoView** I resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi this is a working forked code please find as below

```
const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled', // or 'top'
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
  scrollOffset: [0, 64],
};

@NgModule({
  exports: [RouterModule],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRouteList, routerOptions)],
})
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lrcuxh?file=src/app/informations/informations.component.css)

Comment: thanks the link provided is already working. The problem is in my app.....